# Can't get value from JSON in AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

im a newbie :)

I searched my questions, there are some topic but they dont are like my specific question.

I have an Ajax call for update a form, i can see the values in the `console.log()`, but I can't take the values for insert in the input or divs, here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'my-web-service',
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
                $('#json').append('<div>' + json[i].name + '</div>');
            }
            console.log(json)
        }
    });
});
```

---

My JSON data is :

```
{
  "experience": [
    [
      "58b407cd30f8c7a508004210",
      {
        "artistInfo": {
          "id": "f8d3a411",
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "test",
        "description": "testing",
        "tipology": null,
        "email": "ext_link",
        "externalLink": "www.mywebstite.com",
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: so what does the data look like?

Comment: Is it not `'<div>' + json[i].name + '</div>'` ?

Comment: '<div>' + json[i].name + '</div>'

Comment: You'll need to include at least the structure of the response even if you want to change the specific data returned.

Comment: `dataType: "text"` is that correct?

Comment: doens't the dataType have to be "json" ?

Comment: It depends on what's returned, also note the `$.parseJSON` after - if it's returning JSON, you wouldn't then parse it.   It should *probably* not specify dataType (or specify json as the dataType) and allow jquery to auto convert it (assuming json is returned).

Comment: json returning properly, i tried with datatype: json and without "datatype", still have issues

Comment: Your json doesn't seem to validate. Can you double check that?

Comment: Have you tried: `json.experience[i][2].name`?

Comment: Yes, i get a value, but i can't do this also for [i][3] or [i][4] etc.

Comment: The `for` loop should be: `for (var i = 0; i < json.experience.length; ++i) {` and access method: `json.experience[i][2].name`

Comment: @DhruvSaxena This Works! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Experience is an array within an array(???),
You should fix it or access it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

for the look of it, if you can see the json in the console log, then is probably a problem of data type, are you sure it is an array?

```
json[i].name
```

this could be an object and not accesible as an array. check for the dataType. or post the output of your WS

after reading your post of the data is very clear you are trying to access it the wrong way, it as an array were your first entry is a String, then comes an Object which holds no property name, and finally a third Object which i guess you are trying to get the name.

```
json['experience'][2].name

{  
   "experience":[  
      [  
         "58b407cd30f8c7a508004210",
         {  
            "artistInfo":{  
               "id":"f8d3a411",

            }
         },
         {  
            "name":"test",
            "description":"testing",
            "tipology":null,
            "email":"ext_link",
            "externalLink":"www.mywebstite.com",

         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: How I can access to Third Object without using an array? Because I tried to use "json[2].name" and I got undefined values

Answer (score 0):

i prefere to remove your dataType condition, change the type to POST (you need it when your would send some Data) and skip your JSON parser, it is already parsed and would throw an Exception.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { }, // when you need it
        url: 'my-web-service',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json)

            for (var i = 0; i < json['experience'].length; ++i) {
                for (var i2 = 0; i2 < json['experience'][i].length; ++i2) {
                    if( json['experience'][i][i2].name ) {
                        $('#json').append('<div>' + json['experience'][i][i2].name + '</>');
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer, with type POST i get Undefined values, with GET i get nothing....but in console.log(json) i can see the data...so i don't know how to fix

Comment: When I use type:POST i get nothing, with GET I get a single Undefined Item

Comment: EDIT: with json['experience'][i][2].name i get the data, but i can't see the other values, like [i][3], [i][4]

Comment: here you have now all names of all array elements